# emberjs ember-cli - how to remove deprecated notice for {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

This is using **ember-cli 0.2.3**

**(model) todo.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')  
}).reopenClass({
   FIXTURES: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Complete Ember.js Tutorial",
        isCompleted: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Checkout some more ember stuff",
        isCompleted: true
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Solve world hunger (with Ember)",
        isCompleted: false
      }
   ]
});
```

**in router.js**

```
this.resource('todos', { path: '/' });
```

in todos.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('todo');
    }
});
```

**in todos.hbs**

```
{{#each}}
    //some code here using the model
{{/each}}
```

**in developer console got this notice:**

```
DEPRECATION: Using the context switching form of {{each}} is deprecated. 
Please use the keyword form (`{{#each foo in bar}}`) instead
```

Please advice on the actual each code for removing the deprecation notice.

**The following are codes that I tried:**

```
1 - {{#each todo in todo}} //no error, but no data in todo list
2 - {{#each todo in controller.todo}} //no error, but no data in todo list
3 - {{#each todo in todos.todo}} //no error, but no data in todo list
4 - {{#each todo in todos}} //no error, but no data in todo list
```

***THANK YOU - for any help, cheers!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{#each todo in model}}
  <li>{{todo.title}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: awesome, thank you :D. I want to accept, but the system allow in about 5 minutes haha. Super fast. Did you just waiting for ember.js SO question?

Comment: No, just randomly saw it on New.

Comment: It does worth mentioning that the official syntax is going to be `{{each model as |todo|}}` in the near future.